# Can I use Styrofoam packaging pieces as insulation?

Tags: insulation, styrofoam

I have a walk in closet that’s 12 feet long. The one wall is an outside wall with a high shelf and a hanger rod underneath the 12 foot length. It is very cold in this closet.

Would it create a problem if I put 2 inch thick pieces of Styrofoam along that one wall?

My clothes would all hang on the rod and sort of hold the large pieces of Styrofoam in place.

Comment: I take it you don't want to do anything permanent to that closet? Maybe you are in a rental?

Comment: Sounds like you've got Styrofoam packing from things you've received in the mail. Those always tend to crumble and shed little balls of foam everywhere. Those little ball stick (through the magic of static electricity) to _everything_ and are very difficult to get off. So long as you don't consider wearing your insulation out in public, you should be good...

Comment: The problem with this sort of insulation is that condensation is likely to form on the cold, outer wall. You probably need a damp-proof layer on the closet side of the insulation.

Comment: @Peterbill "This sort" meaning "insulation attached to the inner side of a wall". The reason is that the wall will be cold but will be exposed to the moist warm air in the room. The room air does not *appear´* moist, mind you; in winter it is actually *relatively* dry -- relative to the amount of moisture it *could* hold. In absolute terms though it holds more moisture than air can hold that is as cold as the outer wall, which is why moisture condenses there. The vapor barrier is needed to prevent the warm, moist air from reaching the cold parts of the wall, behind the insulating layer.

Comment: The cold closet may actually mitigate any moth problems.

Comment: Large pieces of bubble wrap may be a better material here.   Its also workable on single-glazed window glass.

Answer (score 15):

Exposed styrofoam could be a fire-spreading hazard. I know that when installed permanently it *must* be behind a barrier material, typically wallboard or plywood, for that reason. For loose pieces... well, the hazard still exists, but I don't think code forbids you piling up the stuff if you want to do so.

Comment: A sheet of cardboard in front of the styrofoam to keep the stuff in place might be nice. Should also prevent damage (granules coming off) from clothes/clothes-hangers bumping into the foam. And it still wouldn't count as a permanent installation (in case code or a landlord would object to doing something permant).

Comment: Ah, yes, but a piece of cardboard, @Tonny, would only help spread a fire faster. Of course, all the clothes hanging in there would spread it pretty quickly too...

Comment: @FreeMan: Yep. I honestly don't have an opinion on whether this is a good thought or not; too many variables.

Comment: @FreeMan The Styrofoam is probably more flammable than the cardboard or the clothes. Bit of a moot point if you have a fire. You're screwed with or without the Styrofoam/cardboard/clothes.

Comment: It's not just how fast a fire spreads, but what kind of smoke it makes.  Plastics make very toxic smoke that incapacitates & kills faster than smoke from wood products and natural fibers.

Comment: @FreeMan I also think that the styrofoam will be your least problem if you have a fire in your walk-in closet (especially with synthetics).

Answer (score 3):

I have used packing styrofoam for some construction material purposes in the past, as a proof of concept.

For starters, it is a **hideous mess.** Regardless how neatly you install it, there will always be little bits of it all over your stuff... your clothing in this case. You can mitigate this slightly by putting it in reused LDPE bags (the sort that they use to pack things like furniture inside the box) but this *must* be done at another place that is well separated.

Next, **shaping** it reasonably is difficult. After I did this experiment, I started to collect clean styrofoam in useful sizes, like sheets or large blocks, so that I have them on hand the next time I do this. Bagging it can be slightly useful for this if you have a strong (and well-filtered) vacuum to evacuate the rest of the air in the bag. Basically, it would take the shape of the bag.

Along the lines of shaping, there are **very few options for glue** that work. Keep in mind that, "work," in this case means it doesn't ruin the insulative properties of the material. I tried many things. Some eat the foam. Others don't stick very well.

As for fire safety, as mentioned by others, I can tell you this as a firefighter: it doesn't matter. Styrofoam doesn't burn really easily but it's not hard to burn. There are other things in your house that will get involved way sooner. It does burn toxic, but nearly everything in a home does these days, to the degree that we don't *ever* enter a burning home without our own air supply. Your clothes will burn just as well and with just as much toxic gas release, as will the carpet, most of your personal items, the backing on just about everything, your trash, etc.

**Please save yourself the trouble** and buy the insulating foam board. (In the US it's generally pink and is quickly becoming the only kind of insulation you can buy at the big box store.) It's made for this exact purpose and some of it is recycled, if that's what your concern is. It is highly likely that you will spend more than you save, both financially and environmentally, to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the wall is framed 2x4 construction, cellulose insulation can be blown into each wall cavity, insulating and air-sealing much better than foam board attached to the inner wall.

Comment: That's assuming you own the property, or the owner is willing to have that done. In which case I'd look at improving insulation for the whole building, not just the closet.

Comment: Be careful with this option. One of the last apartments I lived in didn't report to it's residents that there was asbestos in the walls. They just told us not to go digging into the walls for any reason. You might just find that your landlord gives you the runaround for no discernable reason, and further investigation reveals that they just don't want to replace the insulation in the whole complex.